# How to insert row at index into sorted ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a grid setup with sorting enabled. Each row has a duplicate button. When duplicating a row, I would like to insert the new row just below the copied row. This works with a default sort but if you sort it on a column like for example status, it randomly inserts the row into the grid, making it hard to find.

I have noticed that the grid does a sort sometime during save, yet before it gets a response to assign a new id.

I have tried adding the row using updateRowData(transaction) with an addIndex but it either doesn't insert anything or ignores the index.

I do have access to any component variables from the postSort but I only get a response with an ID after the postSort.

```
cloneRow(item: any): void {
 let newRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.data)) as Object;
 newRow.gridItemId = null;

 this.index = this.api.getFocusedCell().rowIndex;

 this.selectRow(newRow, ++index);
 this.saveRow(newRow);
}

selectRow(newRow: Object, index: number) {
 this.selectedObject = [];
 this.gridItemList.splice(index, 0, newRow);

 this.api.setFocusedCell(index, "ColumnName");
 this.api.startEditingCell({
  rowIndex: index,
  colKey: "ColumnName"
 });
}

saveRow(newRow: Object): void {
 let objectsToSave = new Array<Object>();
 objectsToSave.push(newRow);

 this.CustomService.saveRow(objectsToSave)
  .subscribe(
   (response) => {
    if (!newRow.rowId) {
     newRow.rowId = response[0].rowId;
    }
    this.gridItemList.filter(g => g.gridItemId === response[0].gridItemId)[0] = response[0];
    this.api.refreshCells();
}

postSort = function(rowNodes) {
 console.log("Post Sort");
}
```

Expected: The copied row gets inserted just below the original row.
Actual: The copied row get inserted somewhere in the grid.

Answer (score 5):

> it randomly inserts the row into the grid, making it hard to find.

Actually it's not random, new values could be inserted via [`updateRowData`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#transactions)

`api.updateRowData({add:[listofvalues], addIndex:startIndexPosition})`

where `listofvalues` list of objects to insert (even if it would be just one object), and `startIndexPosition` **index** of position from where insert will start **without sorting**

Let's go deeper, the ag-grid has few *states*:

1. **Default**: it would be displayed exactly how it's passed to `rowData` and on this case `addIndex` is matter, and I suppose only on default state `addInex` is used.
2. **Sorted**: it would be displayed based on sorting conditions.
3. **Grouped**: guess its complex state because groups could be defined as default and has sorting

Simple <kbd>[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WCbnRwCeZ3BqUJEhfTs6?p=preview)</kbd> for demonstration

*try to sort (change to sort asc,desc, and default) by **athlete** and click add row, you will see new rows on start,end and on inserted place (with default state)*

Comment: It looks like someone is giving you serial downvotes (see [your rep page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4483102/un-spike?tab=reputation), but it looks like the recent ones were automatically reversed). There's lots about this on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting).

Comment: yep, part of it was reverted already, but thx anyway will keep in touch.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, agGrid themselves broke (well, depreciated) the `addIndex` functionality in agGrid v23.1....   oh, but they then decided to bring it back with v24.1.

Yes, seriously.

So, the best way to fix this is to first, check if you have an older version of agGrid:

```
npm outdated
```

[image]

And if so, update it using:

```
npm install ag-grid-angularlatest
npm install ag-grid-community@latest
npm install ag-grid-enterprise@latest
```

You now need to add rows into your agGrid using:

```
   let trans:RowDataTransaction = {
       add: [ newRecord ],
       addIndex: 0
   };
   gridApi.applyTransaction(trans);
```