# AG Grid inserting rows with applyTransaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to insert rows at a specific index rather than at the end of the grid?

Example would if I want to insert a row 10 rows from the top? Or in the middle?

I did find an old ag grid method called `insertItemAtIndex(index, [rows]);`

but this isn't working and says it's deprecated. Is there a way to do this with `applyTransaction(transaction)`?

Answer (score 1):

The `RowDataTransaction` interface has an optional `addIndex` property -

```
export interface RowDataTransaction {
    /** deprecated */ addIndex?: number;
    add?: any[];
    remove?: any[];
    update?: any[];
}
```

Although it is marked deprecated, it is working for me.

Usage : `this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ add: newItems, addIndex: 2});`

**It denotes the index  from which new rows will be inserted.**

I have tried playing around on this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/#example-updating-with-transaction) from docs and is working fine.

A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374778/983929) for old way of updating rows. (without transaction)

Comment: I tried this but it's still adding it to the end of the table? api.applyTransaction({add: [newRow], addIndex: 0});

Comment: Do you have any sorting applied? Are you calling any gridapi function after inserting rows?

Comment: No, there's no sorting, and that's the last method i call

Comment: That is interesting. It worked for me when I updated the example from docs. Can you create a plunkr?

Comment: It appears to be working in the plunkr, but I can't tell because I can't get the styles imported: https://plnkr.co/edit/r7rjL7jQ31xoHKYX

Comment: Nvm, I don't think it's working in the plunkr either

Comment: check this out - https://plnkr.co/edit/34OTMTGOu6COTysj  the 3 rows get added starting from specified index when I click the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215530/discussion-between-will-harrison-and-pratik-bhat).

Comment: Sorry did you find out what the cause was? I have the same problem, the row is always added at the end. No matter what

Comment: Just be careful with the addIndex value.  agGrid removed (depreciated) this in v23.1....  then decided to put it back in, in v24.1.   The examples on their website do still use addIndex, so I'm not quite sure what they are playing at....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, where I was using like this

```
this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ add: newItems, addIndex: newIndex});
```

Where **newIndex** was of type 'any', due to which js considers it as a different data type and it was inserting at the end/random place.

Solution:

```
this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ add: newItems, addIndex: parseInt(newIndex) });
```

Now it considers it as a number/integer and inserts in the required position.

Answer (score 0):

As `addIndex` didn't work for me (using tree data in v26.1), I created a new column just for ordering. It is hidden, has sort set to 'asc' and has a `valueGetter` that generates the correct order.