# Add row in ag-grid-angular at bottom of list despite sorting

Tags: angular

I have ag grid with list items - a have to add new row at end of list, but sorting place new row at bottom or at start list.

example from

[How to insert row at index into sorted ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364022/how-to-insert-row-at-index-into-sorted-ag-grid)

```
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ add: [{athlete:"Aaaaaaaaaaa"+Date.now()}], addIndex: this.gridApi.getLastDisplayedRow() + 1 })
```

plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/1AnxJmDmxmutXPM7

Answer (score 1):

Issue explanation - So if you refer ag-grid documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/), clearly mentions when adding a row ag-grid will recalculate the sorting/filtering etc. So depending on the order you have sorted new row comes at top or bottom

Options - Now ag-grid does not provide by default anything to get this sorted, following ar the options you can explore to get desired result

1. Custom Sorting – Write custom comparator to always get the blank values either at top or bottom. There will still be cases where blank is valid value and difficult to isolate the new row
2. Reset Sort Model to null –  Works but while refreshing row data, there is no consistent pattern in the order of rows
3. Post Sort – Ag-grid provides a hook to do any thing that you want after the sorting is done. Details [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#post-sort)

I used "Post Sort" hook to get rows at the bottom. My logic required to get the newly added row at the bottom. So in descending order the new row was at last index and in ascending order new row should be in top lines based on how many columns are empty. Logic step

1. While creating new row add a field identifying it is new row

> ```
> const createNewRow = (columnDefs) => {
>   const rowData = Object.fromEntries((columnDefs || []).map((colDef) => [colDef.field, undefined]))
>   rowData[NEW_ADDED_ROW_IDENTIFIER] = true
>   return rowData
> }
> ```

2. In Post sort look for the newly added row and move to the desired place and delete the "NEW_ADDED_ROW_IDENTIFIER" field

> ```
> const postSortCall = (rowNodes = []) => {
>   if (rowNodes.length >= 1) {
>     const lastIndex = rowNodes.length - 1
>     const addedNodeIndex = (rowNodes[lastIndex].data[NEW_ADDED_ROW_IDENTIFIER]) ? lastIndex
>       : rowNodes.findIndex((rowNode) => rowNode.data[NEW_ADDED_ROW_IDENTIFIER])
>     if (addedNodeIndex >= 0) {
>       delete rowNodes[addedNodeIndex].data[NEW_ADDED_ROW_IDENTIFIER]
>       rowNodes.splice(lastIndex, 0, rowNodes.splice(addedNodeIndex, 1)[0]);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's now November 2020, I'm using agGrid v23.1, and am seeing the same behavior with `addIndex` not working anymore.

I have raised a ticket with agGrid.

When my Angular app attempts to insert a new row a the top of the grid, it now always appears at the bottom, and a warning appears in the Console:

```
ag-grid-community.cjs.js:29229 ag-Grid: as of v23.1, 
transaction.addIndex is deprecated. If you want precision control of adding data, use immutableData instead
```

So, `addIndex` is depreciated, oh, but the agGrid examples continue to use `addIndex`:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/

Worse still, reading the agGrid changelog, they now have an item saying that in v24.1 they will "*Reintroduce addIndex to allow inserting records at a specific index*"

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/

So, if you're seeing this problem when using addIndex, make sure you upgrade your agGrid libraries to v24.1 or later:

```
npm install ag-grid-angular@latest
npm install ag-grid-community@latest
npm install ag-grid-enterprise@latest
```